# Who creates utun0 adapter?

Tags: mac, macos, vpn

Today I looked at the interfaces on my Mac and so I saw the adapter "utun0" on the Mac, this is just for VPN Connections or "Back to my Mac" thought. I have never VPN enabled and "Back to my Mac" is not enabled. Is the adapter creates by default or what program creates it?
Something is afraid of malware / adware / viruses, etc.

I use Sierra.
It's a FE80 also a local address ... I mainly installed Firefox and Photoshop

Best regards

Answer (score 13):

utun0 is created by macOS for VPN and Back to My Mac, regardless of whether these features are enabled. This is not indicative of any unwanted application being installed; utun0 is expected on macOS Sierra and later.

Comment: So the adapter will default to MacOS Sierra and later, regardless of whether the "Back to my Mac" feature is on or off?

Comment: @Honos Yes I believe so

Comment: how to remove utun1, utun2 ?  my mac has problems with connecting to VPN, i believe because of 3 utun interfaces.